# Finding the corners of a puzzle piece

Tags: opencv, image-processing, bufferedimage, javacv, imagej

---

Scenario:

### Scan a puzzle and let a computer solve it (Java application).

I'm searching for a way to find the corners of a jigsaw puzzle piece.

[image]

I don't know if I can approach this problem using a framework. Can I use something like a template here to find the corners? Or do I have to implement an algorithm by myself?

I need to bring a single piece into a straight position. If I'd got both corners, I could calculate the needed angle to rotate the image to a straight level.
I don't need a function like this in a specific framework.

**(Optional)** My approach was:
Implementing an algorithm by myself (propably extremely unperformant).

1. Create a 2D-array where all the white pixels are allocated with 0 and all the colored/black pixels with 1.
2. loop trough the 2D-array ans search for a pixel with 1. From here, search all his neighboring 1.
3. If there are less than 50 neighboring 1, ignore this "pixel" and proceed (scanning error)
4. If there are more than 50 neighboring 1, it is a puzzle piece (and no scanning error). Finish the piece and copy all of them into a fresh 2D-array where no scanning errors should appear.
5. In the fresh array, search for the angles...

Comment: Friendly recommendation - Use Image Processing libraries like OpenCV instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: @Itay: Thanks, but that is part of my question. Do you think this can be solved easily using OpenCV?

Comment: Yes, of course. The solution itself depends on the features of your pieces (if the corners are exactly 90 degrees etc.). You can look at the third chapter of [this article](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~estherw/final/writeup.pdf) (3 Recognizing Sides of a Piece
)

Comment: Also this: http://help.simplecv.org/question/1217/analyze-contour-of-jigsaw-puzzle-pieces/

Comment: @Itay: Thank you! :) I'll read this as soon as I get the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert with OpenCV but I had a go with a Harris Corner Detector as follows:

```cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Compile and run under OSX with:
// clang++ -O3 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) harris.cpp -o harris && ./harris
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int thresh = 200;

int main( )
{
   Mat src,gray;
   // Load image and convert to greyscale
   src=imread("jigsaw.jpg",1);

   cvtColor(src,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
   Mat dst,dst_norm,dst_norm_scaled;
   dst=Mat::zeros(src.size(),CV_32FC1);

   // Detect corners
   cornerHarris(gray,dst,7,5,0.05,BORDER_DEFAULT);

   // Normalize
   normalize(dst,dst_norm,0,255,NORM_MINMAX,CV_32FC1,Mat());
   convertScaleAbs(dst_norm,dst_norm_scaled);

   // Draw circles around corners
   for(int j = 0;j<dst_norm.rows;j++){
      for(int i = 0;i<dst_norm.cols;i++){
         if((int)dst_norm.at<float>(j,i)>thresh){
            circle(dst_norm_scaled,Point(i,j),10,Scalar(255,255,255),1,8,0);
         }
      }
   }

   // Display result
   //imwrite("result.png",dst_norm_scaled);
   namedWindow("corners_window",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   imshow("corners_window",dst_norm_scaled);

   waitKey(0);
   return(0);
}
```

And drew some circles around the identified corners for fun.

[image]